# How to create files with dynamic heights

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I'm wanting to make layered "cards" for print design (think of a tabbed index card but the tab goes the whole width) they'll be layered on 8 1/2x 11. Each card maybe 6in wide.

The thing I wish I could do is keep the heading (top tab of the card) a fixed height while letting the body vary in height based on content.

I can do it with multiple objects obviously but drop shadows get messed a little up so I'm stuck with manually making each height I need and grouping them.

**Is there any way to set the header height but be able to adjust the overall height for each different card I need?**

I'm ultimately doing this in indesign but illustrator would be fine too

Comment: Screenshot worths 1000 words

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD - could you show us some screenshots of what you want to achieve and where you are at?

Comment: Does using the paragraph options for `Space After` on the header or `Space Before` on the contents help? I too am having some difficulty envisioning what you are referring to.

Comment: Sorry guys, I was asking on my iPhone so that's why no screenshots, but grouping and shadowing does effectively do what I want. I must have been doing something wrong before. Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with InDesign CC or CS6, use Auto-size. This is in the `Text Frame Options` dialog (`Ctl/Cmd-B` or  `Object > Text Frame Options...`). Set "Auto-Sizing" to "Height Only" as below, then you can keep everything in a single text frame.

[image: Auto Size]

For earlier versions of InDesign, grouping the objects doesn't get in the way so much if you apply an Object Style to the *group* and define the Drop Shadow as part of the Object Style. TypeFi and DTP Tools both make plug-ins for Id CS5 and earlier that allow text frames to expand and contract automatically.